# Is address of structure members defined behavior?

Tags: c

Sometimes I do pointer arithmetic on structures and I'm not certain if it's defined behavior or not..

If I have this structure

```
typedef struct SCustomData{
    uint32_t a;
    uint32_t b;
}CustomData;
```

Rather than having to constantly type out different fields of the structure sometimes to me it makes sense to just give it a constant size and fit whatever I need to in there.

My first question is: Is it defined behavior that the address of the structure is also the address of the first variable in the structure?

```
int main(){
    CustomData cd = {0};
    cd.a = 0xDEADBEEF;
    
    uint32_t a = 0;
    
    memcpy(&a,&cd,sizeof(uint32_t));
    
    assert(a==0xDEADBEEF);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

Will that always succeed?

My next question is, can I use pointer arithmetic to access any member of the structure so long as I know the sizes of each member?

```
int main(){
    CustomData cd = {0};
    
    cd.b = 0xABCD0000;
    uint16_t highshort = *(uint16_t*)((uint8_t*)&cd+sizeof(uint32_t)+sizeof(uint16_t));
    
    assert(highshort == 0xABCD);
    
    uint8_t highbyte = *(uint8_t*)((uint8_t*)&cd+sizeof(uint32_t)+sizeof(uint16_t)+sizeof(uint8_t));
    
    assert(highbyte == 0xAB);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Aside from maybe looking ugly or bad code practice, is at least defined behavior? Should I avoid it?

And if I didn't use pointer casting and used memcpy instead is it still a bad idea?

```
int main(){
    CustomData cd = {0};
    cd.b = 0xABCD0000;
    uint16_t highshort = 0;
    memcpy(&highshort, ((uint8_t*)&cd)+sizeof(uint32_t)+sizeof(uint16_t), sizeof(uint16_t));
    
    assert(highshort == 0xABCD);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) yes. 2) You may want to do some research about padding bytes in structs 3) same as 2)

Comment: @Gerhardh What if the structures are always correctly alligned/padded? to say, 4, 8, 16, 32

Comment: Regarding the second question (which is essentially same as third) you might create some structs with large members and single smaller members in between them. Check with `offsetof` where they are located.

Comment: @Gerhardh Woah! I actually didn't even know offsetof was a thing!

Comment: Pointer arithmetics is only defined for members of the same array. Different struct members are not an array. => undefined

Comment: @Gerhardh Pointer arithmetic is defined within an object, not just an array. How else could you use offsetof?

Comment: @Barmar Does that imply its defined so long as you know the operating systems' padding and allignment?

Comment: @Kayla `offsetof()` takes the padding into account, you shouldn't try to do it yourself with `sizeof`.

Comment: @Barmar I've never seen an `offsetof` implementation using pointer arithmetics. Do you have a sample?

Comment: @Gerhardh I mean when you do `(char*)&object + offsetof(objecttype, member)`. That's pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @Barmar So I should use offset to get the offset of the member, then use bitshifting to access the inner high,low bits?

Comment: Yes, that's the portable way to do it.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I'll definitely do it that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### First Question

It's actually is defined in the C standard! Section `6.7.2.1` (in this [standard draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf))

> 15 Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in which bit-fields
> reside have addresses that increase in the order in which they are declared. **A pointer to a
> structure object, suitably converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
> bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.** There may be unnamed
> padding within a structure object, but not at its beginning.

##### Second Question

It's not defined according to the standard (again section `6.7.2.1`):

> Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation-
> defined manner appropriate to its type.

However, most compilers align the same way (per-architecture and bitness at least)

#### Why It's still a bad idea

- Maintainability - Your code will be much easier to maintain if you use the members themselves. It won't be dependent on the compiler and bitness, and won't be sensitive to changes in your code (such as changing types or reordering members).
- Readability - Your intentions will of course be much clearer.
- [Sometimes compilers do weird stuff ;)](https://lwn.net/Articles/722293/)

Comment: Thank you! As for the second method , Barmar and Gerhardh mentioned I can use offsetof to get specific member offset then use bitshifting the access individual bits/bytes. So I'll use the combination of the two.

Comment: The true reason why the second example is undefined is accessing an l-value of type `uint32_t` via a pointer to `uint16_t`. This operation violates strict aliasing rule defined in `6.5p7`

Comment: @tstanisl But wouldn't it be okay to do that so long as you know the size of the type? Since I'm using fixed width types I should be able to cast a uint32_t to a uint16_t correct?